# How to make a datagrid double column nullable

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid, nullable

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `DataTable`. Some of the column are of type double. As you know, double doesn't accept `null` value, and the column doesn't accept `double`? (or `Nullable<double>`) as its type. How can I make the column to accept `null` values?

Comment: The type of the column will be `System.Double` but it accepts null values anyway,  you have to pass them as [`DBNull.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx). If the table was loaded with a `DataAdapter` you don't need to do anything.

Comment: It is a Two-way bind. So the user may delete a cell. Then the empty cell will become red and other cells cannot be selected.

Answer (score 2):

```
((DataGridBoundColumn)e.Column).Binding.TargetNullValue = string.Empty;
```

Try setting `DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs` as an event handler when the column is created, and doing the above. This will let your data columns accept empty values when of type double.

Comment: Beautiful. Goes well with if (e.PropertyType.IsGenericType && e.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = DBNull.Value
```

Comment: the cell value is not updated yet for me to make it DBNull

Comment: Every column has property `ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"`. It converts not filled values to `null`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using a Converter associated with the binding that translates the "" or null to DBNull.value

```
//Converter to accept null values in Datagrid not String columns
class DatagridContentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || ((value.GetType() == typeof(String) && (String)value == "")))
        {
            return DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```